# Merging Amplify and NodeJS authentication

Tags: node.js, react-native, aws-amplify

I have an React Native app that has a `nodejs` server. I have implemented google and apple login flows in my nodejs server and it works just fine.

Now I want to use some of the services of `AWS Amplify` that requires `Amplify Auth` . However I don't want to remove my implementation and convert all the users to `AWS Amplify Users`.

Is there a way to authenticate my already authenticated users to AWS Amplify without letting my users to go through setting a password and email combinations again?

Thanks